# Running a web application within ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap, javascript

I'm interested in creating a component / plugin for ArcMap that works something like ArcGIS online. Ideally a small web app would boot up within a window in ArcMap which would be able to perform functions such as adding a layer and other standard tasks.  In the first instance it would be a search tool, but may perform other activities in the future.

Does anyone know if this is possible within ArcObjects?  Is there an API, perhaps with a set of functions that can be called in JavaScript that can do this?

Thanks

Will

Comment: This is definitely possible with ArcObjects and .NET. I don't see this being done with pure Javascript though.

Comment: To allow the web app to interact with ArcMap I'd have imagined a small JavaScript API would exist which would call the equivalent .NET functions responsible for interacting with ArcMap. So it would be a mixed JS / ArcObjects solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such Javascript API. You'll have to write one yourself, as well as a wrapper that will expose the required ArcObjects to Javascript. All in all, it's definitely neither a trivial task, nor something that can be wiped up in a day or two.